# How to duplicate certain rows when meet certain criteria then do update on its certain column values in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Suppose I have a sample of flight record data that I have, where the 'type' column value is either 1 or 2 (1 for one-way trip, 2 for round trip):

```
customer_id, origin, destination, type
1111, London, Munchen, 2
2222, Rome, Paris, 1
```

I'd like to duplicate certain record(s) that the 'type' value is 2 then swap the value of 'origin' and 'destination' columns of the duplicated record(s) and change both 'type' column values to 1.

The desired output is something like this:

```
customer_id, origin, destination, type
1111, London, Munchen, 1
1111, Munchen, London, 1
2222, Rome, Paris, 1
```

Any helps would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us your attempt, please? What did you try?

Comment: I would recommend not to `UPDATE` anything, but rather to `INSERT` the two "duplicates" for each roundtrip flight, then `DELETE` all the roundtrip records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
WITH update_list AS
(
UPDATE your_table
SET type = 1
WHERE type = 2
RETURNING customer_id, origin, destination
)
INSERT INTO your_table (customer_id, origin, destination, type)
SELECT l.customer_id, l.destination, l.origin, 1
FROM update_list AS l
```